# QGIS Linestring rendering curves between vertex

Tags: qgis, linestring, curved

I'm sure I hit a setting somewhere, but now I can't fix it.

When a linestring shp file is rendered in QGIS it adds curves between my verticies... I want straight lines. How do I turn this off?

In the image below, the yellow is a GPX track, and the blue is shp file I created using Save Feature As -> Shape File

[image]

Comment: could you also post a screenshot from your export window in order for others to be able to see your options?

Comment: I just re-exported, and it worked fine this time... I'll see if I can recreate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently I accidentally clicked the "Curved Arrows" Function in the layer styling options. Had nothing to do with the export, everything to do with the rendering.

Check box, second to the bottom:

[image]