# Lines will not stop curving, can't draw a straight line

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am new to QGIS and I realize this is probably a really silly question but I am at my wits end I've been trying to solve this for hours. I need to make a simple line layer to represent the sewer system through town but my "straight lines" will not stop curving out!

What can I do about this?

I think it has something to do with the "add circular string" tool I just can't seem to turn it off?

[image: Photo shows a curved line, need this line to be straight/parallel to the lines beside it]

Comment: It could be the arrow style: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328689/qgis-linestring-rendering-curves-between-vertex/328691#328691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JGH correctly pointed out, the problem is the arrow style you're using.

Here's what a line looks like with the "simple line" style:

[image]

Here's what the same line looks like with the default "arrow" style:

[image]

**The solution is to switch to a "simple line" style, OR if you want to keep using the arrow style, to un-check the box for "curved arrows."**

[image]

Here's what the same line looks like with non-curved arrows:

[image]

Comment: That was it! Thank you all so much I can't believe I didn't think of that!!

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the top toolbar (toolbar panel?) and checking Shape Digitizing Toolbar.

You should be able to turn off Add Circular String that way.

To clarify: if you click Add Circular String, all new segments will curve from then on. You have to click on the Add Line Feature tool (that's what worked for me).

Comment: Please don’t clarify using comments on your own answer  you can [edit] it.